# Horizontal spacing in enumitem

Tags: enumitem

I am using customized indentation in the enumitem package. The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[align=left,wide=4pt]
\item Compute the sums: $1 + 1$, $2 + 2$, $3 + 3$, $4 + 4$, $5 + 5$, $6 + 6$, $7 + 7$, $8 + 8$, $9 + 9$, $10 + 10$, $11 + 11$
\item Compute the products: $1 \times 1$, $2 \times 2$, $3 \times 3$, $4 \times 4$, $5 \times 5$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

produces the following output
[image]
I would like the $10 + 10$ to align with the "Compute the sums" text; essentially I would like to move the entire text block over by some length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way. Note `align=left` is not needed, as it is set by the `wide`option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=4pt, leftmargin=*, labelsep=1cm]
\item Compute the sums: $1 + 1$, $2 + 2$, $3 + 3$, $4 + 4$, $5 + 5$, $6 + 6$, $7 + 7$, $8 + 8$, $9 + 9$, $10 + 10$, $11 + 11$, $ 12 + 12$, $ 13 + 13$. \item Compute the products: $1 \times 1$, $2 \times 2$, $3 \times 3$, $4 \times 4$, $5 \times 5$. \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't *quite* what I wanted. The alignment works out great, but how can I modify the space between "1." and "Compute"

Comment: @Nitin: You have to play with  the `labelsep` key. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Sounds like a graphic mock up of what you want would go a long way in clarifying your question.

Comment: @AFeldman most definitely, but thankfully Bernard and Andrew were patient.

Comment: :) yes, I noticed.

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour of [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package is what you are asking for but you have turned off this geature by setting `wide=4pt`. According the enumitem manual, the key-option `wide` has the following effect:

> With this convenience key [wide], the leftmargin is null and the label is part of the text—in other word, the items look like ordinary paragraphs.

I think that perhaps you meant to write something like `widest=10`, because the following MWE does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[align=left,widest=10]
\item Compute the sums: $1 + 1$, $2 + 2$, $3 + 3$, $4 + 4$, $5 + 5$, $6 + 6$, $7 + 7$, $8 + 8$, $9 + 9$, $10 + 10$, $11 + 11$
\item Compute the products: $1 \times 1$, $2 \times 2$, $3 \times 3$, $4 \times 4$, $5 \times 5$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

producing:

[image]

Note that the `wide` option is not necessary for this.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted. I wanted to be able to move the block of text left and right, somewhat like "wide" but with the modification that the block of text be moved entirely.

Comment: Sorry if I am being slow, but I don't understand what you mean. Could you add an explicit example to your question?

Comment: So you see how the "$9 + 9$" in your MWE is aligned with the "Compute"? I want that, but I would like for the entire text after "1." to be shifted over to the left a bit. My example with "wide" was to show the deficiency I wanted to amend.

Comment: @Nitin: I think you are looking for the `leftmargin=*` option.

Comment: @PeterGrill not quite so (I think). See my comment on Bernard's post.